# Should I use a var per each require?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any argument to using `1` or `2` here?

```
// 1
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

// 2
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    user = require('./routes/user'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path');
```

I tend to use `2` but would be interested to know if there is a correct way, or if it's all just as-you-like?

Comment: This is as you like because in both ways your variables will be defined.

Comment: 2 is cleaner as does the same thing, i don't see a downside...

Comment: Both ways are correct for defining variables, you whichever you wish.

Comment: I use leading commas instead of trailing. IMO, it makes it easier to see if one was missed.

Comment: ...while making it look like somebody threw up on your code :)

Comment: Thanks guys, and for the duplicate mark. Couldn't find that before.

Comment: It is generally a good advice to go with a second choice, but use a comma-first style. Especially if your variable list is very long like [this one](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/8e879f558e15dae25ee81da7d73164896050f8ea/lib/cache.js#L60)